# How to connect to any SSL enabled Cassandra cluster with latest version of java-driver-core

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

My cluster is having following configurations

```
protocol: TLS
algorithm: SunX509
store_type: JKS
```

Following is the code of 3.4 java driver which is working.

```
Cluster.builder()
                .addContactPoints(hostNameList)
                .withCredentials(username, password)
                .withPort(port)
                .withSSL(getSslOptions()).build().connect();
```

```
 private static SSLOptions getSslOptions() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sc.init(null, new TrustManager[]{new TrustAllX509TrustManager()}, new SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier((string, ssls) -> true);
        return RemoteEndpointAwareJdkSSLOptions.builder().withSSLContext(sc).build();
    }
```

```
public class TrustAllX509TrustManager implements X509TrustManager {
    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
    }
    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
    }
    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return new X509Certificate[0];
    }
}
```

Similarly, I am trying with 4.5 java driver But I am getting error - com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException: Could not reach any contact point

Code

```
        CqlSession.builder()
                .withAuthCredentials(username, password)
                .addContactPoints(Arrays.stream(hostNameList).map(host -> new InetSocketAddress(host, port)).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .withSslContext(getSslContext()).build();
```

```
    private SSLContext getSslContext() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sc.init(null, new TrustManager[]{new TrustAllX509TrustManager()}, new SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier((string, ssls) -> true);
        return sc;
    }
```

I want a general approach that is why I am not passing keystore details.